# VPN not working on Android when on Wifi Network

Tags: wi-fi, vpn

I have a Synology NAS server that has a L2TP/IPSec PSK VPN Server running. I used to connect to it with my Android phone (Version 7) (and previously with my iPhone) just fine. Whether I was on 4G or on a Wifi, it always connected without problems.

I have recently replaced my Android phone with a new one (Huawei P30 Pro) that runs on Android 9. The strange thing here is, that I can connect to the VPN when I am on a 4G network, but when I try to connect to the VPN when I am on a Wifi connection, it does not work and comes back with an unsuccessful message.

I am pretty confident that it is not the Wifi network, as I can still connect to the VPN with my old phone side-by-side, but the new one is not working.

Is there any way to troubleshoot the VPN connection to figure out where the problem is? Is there any log files I can check on the phone? Or do you have any hints why that could be?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Have you tried it with different networks?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same in two different Wifi networks.

Comment: Matth, have you solved your problem? I am facing the same problems.

Comment: I gave up on L2TP/IPSec. I managed to get it to work with OpenVPN.